# What happens if my passport expires while I am in a different country?

Tags: usa, uk, passports

I'm an American. If I travel to the UK for the first time as a tourist and my passport expires while i am still visiting, what would happen?

Answer (score 12):

[The US State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/UnitedKingdom.html) and [the UK Government](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control) say that your passport should be valid for the entire duration of your stay. Before you fly to the UK, your airline will check your travel documents and will see a message saying that "- Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for the period of intended stay."

As such, you might not get to have this problem, because you run a high risk of the airline denying you boarding. If you do make it to the UK border, you run a risk of being refused entry or having your authorized period of stay limited to the validity duration of your passport. These are all good ways to ruin your vacation.

If none of that happens and you do find yourself in the UK while your passport expires, you'd want to contact the US Embassy or Consulate so that they can get you new travel documents; airlines generally won't let you fly home with an expired passport.

If there's any doubt that your passport could expire during your trip, renew it before you leave ([this can be done quite quickly if your trip is imminent](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/hurry.html)). Note that [many countries require your passport be valid for 3-6 months beyond the period of your intended stay](https://thepointsguy.com/2017/08/six-month-passport-validity-rule/), so there are a lot of places you could be denied entry if your passport expires soon.

Comment: There are standard ways to renew passports abroad for expats, who have long term visa or some such.

Comment: It is a bit unfortunate that the last of the links presents an incorrect "six months after departure" rule for, say, the Schengen countries, where the actual requirement is only _three_ months after the intended departure.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point. I threw that in as an afterthought at the end. Replaced with a slightly better link, at least one that takes the time to provide the correct requirement there.

Comment: @Willeke I'm an American citizen permanently living in the UK. I renewed my US passport only a couple of month ago at the embassy in London.  While the process was painless, the earliest appointment at the Embassy was about 2 weeks from the date I enquired. I then I had to surrender my old passport - and received a new one after about 3 more weeks. Yes, you could renew by post, but you're still looking at minimum 3 weeks without passport.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, what can be done is an emergency travel document from American Embassy, which will let you get back to the USA. This is not a passport, of course.